# Сохранение позиции вертикального скролла у div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Добрый день. На странице идет обновление DIVа таким способом

```
echo'

setInterval(function() {
$("#full").load("get.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'");
}, 5000);
';
```

Мне нужно сохранить позицию скроллбара у элемента #message при таком обновлении.
Использовал такой код:

```
    
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var div = document.querySelector('#message');
   var scroll = localStorage.getItem('scroll')||0;
   div.scrollTop = scroll;
   div.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   localStorage.setItem('scroll', div.scrollTop);
   })
   });
```

Но он работает только при ручной перезагрузке страницы.
Есть какие-либо варианты?
[Ссылка на код](http://ctfdev.ru/code.txt)

Comment: Можно показать ваш HTML код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос. Разделил обновление на 2 действия. У родителя ставил скроллбар и обновлял контент дочернего элемента. Так же и со вторым элементом.
**Вопрос закрыт**